# How to Sum a result quantity in sql server with multiple records which several joins, does it need some subquery to do it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate

I am wanting to get the **SUM** records of a query that I am writing

I have done simple SUM aggregates in the past, but I'm a bit rusty and wonder the best approach to getting the proper results.

Example of table with Quantity  (imaps_inv)

```
ste_id     ste_acct_id    stk_id    qty
 1            1            001       5
 1            2            001      10
 1            3            001      15
```

So the query should NOT return 3 records, but only 1 record and so the query results SHOULD be

```
Site ID     Stocking ID       Qty
    1           001           30
```

So you can see what I want to return

`inv.qty` is the Quantity field I wish to SUM , and the query I wrote up based on the tables is below.

```
SELECT ste.ste_id, ty.ste_ty_id, inv.qty
FROM dbo.imaps_inv inv WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.imaps_ste ste WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON inv.ste_id = ste.ste_id 
INNER JOIN dbo.imaps_ste_ty ty
    ON ty.ste_ty_id = ste.ste_ty_id
INNER JOIN dbo.imaps_stk_acct acct WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON acct.ste_id = ste.ste_id
INNER JOIN dbo.imaps_stk_acct_ty aty WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON aty.stk_acct_ty_id = acct.stk_acct_ty_id
WHERE 
    ste.inact_ind = 0
AND LTRIM(RTRIM(aty.stk_acct_ty_nm)) = 'Good'
AND acct.rsv_ind = 0
AND acct.inact_ind = 0
```

**PLEASE LET ME KNOW WHAT I CAN PROVIDE TO MAKE IT MORE HELPFUL  ( screenshots, schema etc... )**

**UPDATE**,
well I was only getting 19 records and this co-worker said "oh, no.. you should be getting 16,000 records...

I said ok,  i'm using this ste_id  (site id)  and when I sent him this query

```
 SELECT distinct ste_id from [dbo].[imaps_inv]    ( 20 records)
```

He said, to add in stk_id (stock #)

```
SELECT distinct ste_id, stk_id from [dbo].[imaps_inv]  (15,910 records)
```

Therefore I updated my query to which I finally have the proper results and figured I would update my question with the combination of the persons answer along with me tweaking the code as other person certainly does not have the schema and records etc..

**Final working query**

```
SELECT ste.ste_id as 'Site ID', inv.stk_id as 'Stocking ID', SUM(inv.qty) Qty
FROM dbo.imaps_inv inv WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.imaps_ste ste WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON inv.ste_id = ste.ste_id 
INNER JOIN dbo.imaps_ste_ty ty
    ON ty.ste_ty_id = ste.ste_ty_id
INNER JOIN dbo.imaps_stk_acct acct WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON acct.ste_id = ste.ste_id
INNER JOIN dbo.imaps_stk_acct_ty aty WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON aty.stk_acct_ty_id = acct.stk_acct_ty_id
WHERE 
    ste.inact_ind = 0
AND LTRIM(RTRIM(aty.stk_acct_ty_nm)) = 'Good'
AND acct.rsv_ind = 0
AND acct.inact_ind = 0
GROUP BY ste.ste_id, inv.stk_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SUM`:

```
SELECT  ste.ste_id, 
        SUM(inv.qty) Qty
FROM dbo.imaps_inv inv WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.imaps_ste ste WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON inv.ste_id = ste.ste_id 
INNER JOIN dbo.imaps_ste_ty ty
    ON ty.ste_ty_id = ste.ste_ty_id
INNER JOIN dbo.imaps_stk_acct acct WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON acct.ste_id = ste.ste_id
INNER JOIN dbo.imaps_stk_acct_ty aty WITH(NOLOCK)
    ON aty.stk_acct_ty_id = acct.stk_acct_ty_id
WHERE 
    ste.inact_ind = 0
AND LTRIM(RTRIM(aty.stk_acct_ty_nm)) = 'Good'
AND acct.rsv_ind = 0
AND acct.inact_ind = 0
GROUP BY ste.ste_id;
```

Comment: Column 'dbo.imaps_ste_ty.ste_ty_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @JeremyMiller doesn't seem like you are using my code

Comment: I gather I need to add that column into the group by ,  will that work right,  or will I need to have some subquery ?

Comment: SELECT ste.ste_id, ty.ste_ty_id,  SUM(inv.qty) Qty        need these 3 columns

Comment: @JeremyMiller if you want that column in the `SELECT`, then yes

Comment: Ok,  I suppose this is what I need,  it is easier than I thought.

Comment: When would there arise a situation in which I would do to do a subquery?   I certainly prefer it to be simple , however I refer years ago having to wrestle with subqueries with SUM etc...